# Django- Field appears as Null

Tags: python, django, django-serializer

I want to show the name of a field and not the ID of it, so I tried a couple of different methods but with nothing worked for me. I couldn't figure out why or find a suitable solution for this, so here it goes:
Basically, my views returns a null field when in fact it is not null. Code bellow.

tags = TagListSerializer() # Returns null
tags = serializers.Field(source='tags.name') # Returns null
tags = TagListSerializer # Doesn't change anything

**Comercial** inherits from **Project** which is abstract:

```
class Comercial(Project):
    name = models.CharField()
```

**Project** is abstract:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, editable=True)
```

The **Tag** Model:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=False)
```

The **Comercial View** which searches by tag:

```
class ListComercialAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ComercialListSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        tag = self.request.GET.get('tag')
        if(tag!=None):
            return Comercial.objects.filter(tags__name=tag)
        else:
            return Comercial.objects.all()
```

The **Tag Serializer**:

```
class TagListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('__all__')
```

And finally the **ComercialSerlialzier**:

```
class ComercialListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagListSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Comercial
        fields = ('name', 'tags')
```

At listing the Comercial object I expected something like this:

```
{
"name": "Example Comercial Name"
"tags": {
         "name":"Example Tag Name"}
}
```

But all i get is:

```
{
"name": "Example Comercial Name"
"tags": {
        "name": null
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **To clarify:** The name field in Tag is set as null=False

Answer (score 1):

Well, adding **many=True** to the serializer solved my problem...dumb me

```
class ComercialListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagListSerializer(many=True)
```